# Element is not appearing when I reach it by scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the **element** fade in when i reach it by scrolling. But my **JavaScript** is not working, i dont know what is wrong. Currently i'm trying to learn JavaScript, so please don't answer with *JQuery*!

Here is my snippet:

```js
//variables

var textElement = document.querySelectorAll(".service");
var yScroll = window.scrollTop;
var yPos = textElement.offsetTop / 2;

// function

function scrollFun() {
  if (yScroll > yPos) {
    textElement.style.opacity = '1';
    console.log(yPos);
  } else {
    textElement.style.opacity = '0';
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFun);
```

```css
.service {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</p>

<div class="service">
  <!-- the element that i want to be reveald -->
</div>
```

Comment: I see at least one issue here. querySelectorAll() returns a list of elements, not a single element. You can switch your code to document.querySelectorAll(".service")[0] to grab the first element (since you have only 1 in this case). If you plan on adding more you'll need to loop through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to set your selector to select the first element as mentioned in the comment by mike d.

Secondly, the `var yScroll = window.scrollTop;` needs to be `var yScroll = window.scrollY;`

Thirdly, the assessment of window scroll position needs to be within the function body :

```
function scrollFun() {
var yScroll = window.scrollY;
  if (yScroll > yPos) {
    textElement.style.opacity = '1';
    console.log(yPos);
  } else {
    textElement.style.opacity = '0';
  }
}
```

Comment: here's a fiddle with it working : https://jsfiddle.net/linskin/um2c0z93/1/